# wbemcli: key/value pair output

Tags: bash, wbem

If I use `wbemcli` to enumerate all the instances I get something similar to this:

```
wbemcli -nl -t -noverify ei 'https://aaa/aaa:aaa' 
https://aaa/aaa:aaa.Version="",Vendor="",Name=""
-Version#=""
-Vendor#=""
-Name#=""
-Description=""
```

How can I call `wbemcli` to get only one item (i.e. the `Name`)? and not everything.

The `-t` option says:

> -t
>   Append array ([]), reference (&) and key property (#) indicators to property names

but I wasn't able to utilize this in my favor.

Is there a way to retrieve this information in a key/value pair format?
Or maybe pipe the output into an array or something from which I can grab only what I need?

When I drop the output into an array all the data is stored in the first element `${a[0]}`.

**EDIT**
Here's an output example:

```
$ wbemcli -nl -t -noverify ei 'https://user:pw@000.000.000.000:0000/root/aaa:AA_AaaAaaaAaaaa'
000.000.000.000:0000/root/aaa:AA_AaaAaaaAaaaa.ClassName="AA_AaaAaaaAaaaa",Name="123456a7ff890123"
-ClassName#="AA_AaaAaaaAaaaa"
-Name#="123456a7ff890123"
-Caption="aa aaa"
-Description="aa aa"
-ElementName="aa aaa aaaa"
-OperationalStatus[]=2
-HealthState=5
-CommunicationStatus=2
-DetailedStatus=1
-OperatingStatus=0
-PrimaryStatus=1
-EnabledState=5
-RequestedState=12
-EnabledDefault=2
-TransitioningToState=12
-PrimaryOwnerName="Uninitialized Contact"
-PrimaryOwnerContact="Uninitialized Contact"
```

The output is usually in this format.
If the query returns multiple objects they will be grouped and all will have the same members with their appropriate values.

Comment: Are the values on the lines prefixed with `-` just duplicating the values on the line starting with `https`? Does the output always look like this? Can you run this on multiple URLs at once (and have need to retrieve each `Name` value independently)?

Comment: @EtanReisner I edited my post to reflect your questions.

Comment: Pipe that to `awk -F '[-=]' '$1==Name{print $2}'`? (Assuming neither `-` nor `=` can appear in the keys or values. If it can then you need slightly more than that.)

Answer (score 1):

http://linux.dell.com/files/whitepapers/WBEM_based_management_in_Linux.pdf has a number of examples which simply suggest to use `grep` to obtain the specific key and value you are looking for.  There does not seem to be a way to directly query for a specific key within a result set.

Expanding on the comment by Etan Reisner, you could use something like

```
wbemcli <<query>> | grep -oP "^-$key=\K.*"
```

to obtain the value for the key named in `$key`, provided you have GNU `grep` which provides the `-P` option for Perl-compatible regular expressions (here, the `\K` "forget up through here" operator is useful).  So for your specific example,

```
wbemcli -nl -t -noverify ei 'https://aaa/aaa:aaa' |
grep -oP '^-Name#=\K.*'
```

There is also a `-dx` option which produces XML output, which may be more robust if you are planning to write a major application on top of this protocol (but then perhaps you should be looking at a dedicated WBEM library such as the [C or Java libraries listed in their wiki](http://sblim.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#The_SBLIM_Stack)).  It would not seem to be implausible to write a simple (e.g.) Python client to retrieve (part of?) the result tree and let you query or manipulate it locally, either.